# Twitter username input field text plugin!

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter

I'm looking for a nice plugin that filters a username input field like Twitter.
I tried to user their script but it's impossible to understand.

I found other plugins over the net but they don't usually block special characters like é, á, ç, ã and etc.. Twitter script does!

Do you know where I can find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I went on twitter to have an idea of the behavior. This seems to be a simple masked/filtered input.

A quick google lookup showup many links. This ITGroup.com has a script that does just that. I guess you would have to add a custom filter (it's possible) so it doesn't allow accentuated char, but it's exactly what you want to do.

doc : http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/

zip : http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/alphanumeric.zip

This exemple makes a custom rule and defines only certain characters to prevent, like dot (.), one (1), and a (a). So you can manually add the accentuated character. As tweeter did.

$('.sample6').alphanumeric({ichars:'.1a});

```
<input type="text" class="sample6 tb" size="10" />
```

See doc for full options. It's pretty straight forward, you'll see.